# How to add fixed suffix in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a fixed suffix in a textbox.
For example,

```html
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checked">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num">%
</label>
```

However, in this method, the three part - checkbox, textbox and "%" would be showed in three lines if the window is narrow.

How to let them always show in one line together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [input-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to do this in a nice way.

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19690/)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" id="checked"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num">
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around all the inputs and set a width, this will keep the wrapper at a set width regardless of the page width, see example: https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/7/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checked">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num">%
</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{width: 250px;}
```

**The better option is to use `white-space: nowrap` on the label, see example:** https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/8/

HTML

```
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checked">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num">%
</label>
```

CSS

```
label{white-space: nowrap;}
```